# Select Rows which don't exist in second table based on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql. I have two tables. which don't share a key (but have some attributes in common). I have to select rows from tableA which don't exist in tableB. Based on googling and stack overflow I wrote this query

```
select ta.a, ta.b, ta.c from 
(select a, b, c, -1 * c d from TableA) ta
left join TableB tb on (ta.a = tb.a and ta.b = tb.b and ta.d = tb.c) 
where tb.a is null and tb.b is null and tb.c is null;
```

But I am not sure if this is correct. Can you confirm or tell me if what I wrote is correct?

In the end I should not get any rows from TableA, if TableB had a row which has the same value for a and b and negative value of c.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming none of the key values are `NULL`, you can do it this way.  One `NULL` comparison is suficient:

```
select ta.a, ta.b, ta.c
from TableA ta left join
     TableB tb
     on ta.a = tb.a and ta.b = tb.b and - ta.c = tb.c 
where tb.a is null;
```

I don't recommend using a subquery to define `d`.  MySQL tends to materialize subqueries, which adds additional overhead and can prevent indexes from being used.

Comment: what if some of the columns were nullable?

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch . . . If the columns actually contains `NULL` values (as opposed to merely being "nullable"), you would need to take that into account in the `JOI ` conditions, perhaps using the `NULL`-safe comparison operator.